# Assigning an ID to a dynamically loaded Qt element

Tags: javascript, qt, qt-quick

How can I assign a id to a dynamically loaded Qt element. I tried,

```
var Component1 = Qt.createComponent("Column.qml");
var g =Component1.createObject(column1,{"anchors.left" : column1.right, "id" = xxxx});
```

And also

```
g.id=xxxx;
```

Both don't work. Is there any other way to set an id to a dynamically loaded element.

Comment: Do you mean QML component? If yes, you have to use Component.createObject(), not Component1. Also you have typo in parameters list. It have to be id: "xxx". Name without quotas, value with quotas separated by a colon. Assigning `id` to a new created object also works well

Comment: @folibis I created Component1, also it said in the wiki http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method `component.createObject(parent, {"x": 100, "y": 100});` that's why I did that.(It works if I do it like you said).Also if i assign id to a newly created object, I get a error saying ID does not exist.

Comment: ok, according to Qt help you cannot assign `id` to dynamically created object just because `id` is part of `QML` parsing system. btw for what you need it? `g` is already reference to your object

Comment: @folibis Can you make that comment into an answer so that I can accept it ?